# Unreal Engine - event handling inside 'while...' loop

Tags: c++, timer, event-handling, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to create an event handler, which affects stamina regeneration in-game, for example every 0.75s tick *CurrentStamina* variable should be increased by *BasicStaminaRegen* variable's value. I wanted to include it into a while loop to check at every tick if *CurrentStamina == MaxStamina*.

Concept C++ code:

```
...
float currentStamina = 25.0, maxStamina = 100.0, basicStaminaRegen = 5.0;
while(currentStamina != maxStamina) {
(something related to handle a timer)
...
currentStamina += basicStaminaRegen;
}
...
```

Question is, how can I accomplish it in UE blueprint editor?

[*StaminaRegen* defined function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFRsC.png)

[image]

[Part of code with an appropriate event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AE09.png)

[image]

Comment: Comparing float values that way (for exact equality) is probably a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Then how would you like to do that? I'm afraid there isn't many other ways to check if one variable is equal to another.

Comment: Regarding C++ code you can use the [_epsilon_ approximation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: How much could it impact on the code's overall stability or performance (assuming there's a larg amount of in-game features using this technique)? I'm excluding a potential human factor within code's structure (eg. instead of comparing, re-writing current variable's value - a famous mistake of using = instead of ==).

Comment: _"How much could it impact on the code's overall stability or performance"_ It would impact your performance as much as your `while()` loops condition stays true (it could possibly run infinite). But I'm not sure what really applies here. Are you providing that exact C++ code you posted in your question, or does the Unreal Engine generate something for you? (I'd suspect in the latter case it should be done correctly).

Comment: Anyway, thank you for that advise, it's worth taking into consideration. In this specific case while wouldn't run forever, because it's only related to temporary states, like previously given stamina/health regeneration, which would obviously finish just after leveling off to its initial value, stored in a separated variable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend when the set timer event is running on loop there is no need for a while loop and complicate things just use a simple branch , again I can be wrong.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for reply. I just got my hands on paper tutorial, which will include this type of operations as well (I hope so :p), so sooner or later I'll find out :)